# Defining list from a function with multiple arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the following function:

```
def func(x, y, z):
  d = -5.9
  T = 230.0

  f = x - y * T + z + d

  return f
```

From this, I want to make a single list of f-values extracted from func(x, y, z). The values x, y, and z are three different lists of values.

My question is, how do I make the list of f-values? I have tried the following, but it did not work properly:

```
f_list = [func(x, y, z) for x in x_list for y in y_list for z in z_list]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to use `zip`:

```
f_list = [func(*vals) for vals in zip(x_list, y_list, z_list)]
```

or for clearance:

```
f_list = [func(x, y, z) for x, y, z in zip(x_list, y_list, z_list)]
```

You can also use [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
import itertools
f_list  = list(itertools.starmap(func, zip(x_list, y_list, z_list)))
```